# Why does a move constructor need to use "rvalue reference"?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, move-constructor

For example, the following move constructor works without the `&&` (rvalue reference):

```
Obj::Obj(Obj& obj) : elem { obj.elem }, data(obj.data) {

    obj.elem = nullptr;
    obj.data = 0;

}
```

I don't really understand why it's necessary...

Comment: That is NOT move-constructor. That is a copy-constructor and that too, **a bad one**.

Comment: It's a copy constructor. Well, Nawaz was faster :P.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rvalue reference arguments will refuse to bind to non-rvalue references.  Because of this restriction, `move` operations will only happen when the object being moved from can never be explicitly referred to in code at a later time (because it is a temporary being discarded, or a local variable being returned), or because the caller explicitly `move`d from them.

To see why this is required, you could look up the history of `auto_ptr`, or you could read this example, which uses your `Obj` type:

```
int main() {
  Obj a;
  Obj b = a; // oops!  You just *moved* a into b!
}
```

with a proper `move` constructor, it is only called when the right hand side is a value that is going to be immediately discarded in a way that the compiler can detect, or you call `move`.

On top of that, `&` references refuse to bind to temporaries -- a temporary can only bind to a `const&` or a `&&`.

Answer (score 12):

Your example cannot bind to a temporary, so these would not work:

```
Obj makeObj() { return Obj(); }

Obj o1(Obj());     // Error
Obj o2(makeObj()); // Error
```

Furthermore, it makes it very easy to break things, because you essentially have a copy constructor that steals state away from the object it is copying from:

```
Obj o1;
Obj o2{o1}; // o1 is modified
```

Comment: Bah, forgot to mention this.  Blatantly stealing from your answer!

Comment: I see you returned the favor.  ;)

Comment: @Yakk It might seem that way, but I was too busy typing to notice anything :)

Comment: since I have no way of knowing who plagiarized whom, I gave you both an up-vote

Comment: @JoshG79 I forgot to include the "oh, and it doesn't work with temporaries" part, which is what juan started with, in my answer.  (the last paragraph of my answer I edited in after I realized I forgot that part!)